# iOS UICollectionView: Cells with circular view in alternating grid alignment

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to implement the `UICollectionView` for custom cells in the shape of circle. Now by default the circles are aligned in the same way as the normal square cell: top circle and bottom circle are on the same vertical line. How can I change the alignment to this: the top circle and two circles below it form an equilateral triangle (positions of top circle and bottom circle are shifted by radius' length)? As below:

```
from OOO
     OOO
     OOO

to   O O O
    O O O (no spacing among the circles)
     O O O
```

Comment: You need to create your own `UICollectionViewLayout`, "telling" what's the frame for your cells.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic idea is to create a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` that implements:

- `collectionViewContentSize`, i.e., what's the size of the full, scrollable `contentSize` of the collection view;
- `layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath:)`, i.e., what are the key attributes (namely `center` and `size`) of a particular cell; and
- `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect:)`, i.e., what are the key attributes for cells that fall within this particular `rect` ... this will be used to identify which cells are visible at any given point in time as well as the attributes for those cells; this is basically an array of the attributes for the cells from the previous method, filtered down to just the ones within that `rect`.

Thus, in Swift 3 you could do something like:

```
class AlternatingGridLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    private var itemSize: CGSize!
    private var numberOfItems: Int!
    private var itemsPerRow: Int!
    private var rows: Int!
    private var circleViewCenterOffset: CGPoint!
    private var radiusOfCircleViews: CGFloat!
    private var insets: UIEdgeInsets!

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }

        radiusOfCircleViews = CGFloat(40.0)
        itemSize = CGSize(width: radiusOfCircleViews * 2, height: radiusOfCircleViews * 2)
        circleViewCenterOffset = CGPoint(x: 2 * radiusOfCircleViews * cos(.pi / 3),
                                         y: 2 * radiusOfCircleViews * sin(.pi / 3))
        numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        itemsPerRow = Int(floor((collectionView.bounds.width - radiusOfCircleViews) / CGFloat(2 * radiusOfCircleViews)) + 0.5)
        rows = (numberOfItems - 1) / itemsPerRow + 1
        let excess = collectionView.bounds.width - (CGFloat(itemsPerRow) * radiusOfCircleViews * 2 + circleViewCenterOffset.x)
        insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: excess / 2, bottom: 10, right: excess / 2)
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView!.bounds.width,
                      height: 2 * radiusOfCircleViews + CGFloat(rows - 1) * circleViewCenterOffset.y + insets.top + insets.bottom)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)

        attributes.center = centerForItem(at: indexPath)
        attributes.size = itemSize

        return attributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        return (0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)).map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: 0) }
            .filter { rect.intersects(rectForItem(at: $0)) }
            .compactMap { self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: $0) }  // `flatMap` in Xcode versions before 9.3
    }

    private func centerForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGPoint {
        let row = indexPath.item / itemsPerRow
        let col = indexPath.item - row * itemsPerRow

        var x: CGFloat = radiusOfCircleViews + CGFloat(col) * (radiusOfCircleViews * 2)
        let y: CGFloat = radiusOfCircleViews + CGFloat(row) * (circleViewCenterOffset.y)

        if row % 2 == 0 {
            x += circleViewCenterOffset.x
        }

        return CGPoint(x: x + insets.left, y: y + insets.top)
    }

    private func rectForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGRect {
        let center = centerForItem(at: indexPath)

        return CGRect(x: center.x - radiusOfCircleViews, y: center.y - radiusOfCircleViews, width: radiusOfCircleViews * 2, height: radiusOfCircleViews * 2)
    }        
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Clearly, customize this as you see fit, but it illustrates the basic idea.

---

In my original answer, below, I assumed you wanted to see these cells in a circle, as shown in WWDC 2012 video [Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/219/) (about 40+ minutes into the video). See that below.

---

For example, in Swift 3:

```
class CircleLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    private var center: CGPoint!
    private var itemSize: CGSize!
    private var radius: CGFloat!
    private var numberOfItems: Int!

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }

        center = CGPoint(x: collectionView.bounds.midX, y: collectionView.bounds.midY)
        let shortestAxisLength = min(collectionView.bounds.width, collectionView.bounds.height)
        itemSize = CGSize(width: shortestAxisLength * 0.1, height: shortestAxisLength * 0.1)
        radius = shortestAxisLength * 0.4
        numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return collectionView!.bounds.size
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)

        let angle = 2 * .pi * CGFloat(indexPath.item) / CGFloat(numberOfItems)

        attributes.center = CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(angle), y: center.y + radius * sin(angle))
        attributes.size = itemSize

        return attributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        return (0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))
            .compactMap { item -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? in    // `flatMap` in Xcode versions prior to 9.3
                self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: item, section: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply set the `collectionViewLayout` and then implement the standard `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods.

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var numberOfCells = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = CircleLayout()

        // just for giggles and grins, let's show the insertion of a cell

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                self.numberOfCells += 1
                self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)])
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

extension ViewController {
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfCells
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CircleCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image: circle view]

---

See https://github.com/robertmryan/CircularCollectionView for sample.

---

Note, you mentioned that you want "no spacing among the circles", so just adjust the `radius` and/or `itemSize` accordingly to get the layout you want.

Comment: this is great but can you please tell me how can i make the collectionview spin round endlessly, thanks in advance