# UICollectionView item order using custom layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I am implementing a collection view (vertical scroll) using swift and the ordering of items need to be like below.

---

### Item1 Item5

### Item2 Item6

### Item3 Item7

### Item4 Item8

However, the default flowlayout ordering is like this.

---

### Item1 Item2

### Item3 Item4

### Item5 Item6

### Item7 Item8

Can anyone show me how I can achieve the ordering I need using custom layout?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And when you vertically scroll, you want item 9 under item 4 and item 13 under item 8?

Comment: Actually the collectionView should not be scrollable so if there are odd number of items, for example, item 9, it should go under Item 8.

Comment: Well, the collectionView should be resized to make it fit using overriding intrinsicSize.

Comment: The cell size should stay the same. This collectionView exist inside of UICollectionViewCell. Therefore the parent UICollectionViewCell grows to fit this collectionView.

Comment: Rather than a unscrollable collection view inside a scrollable collection view, I might use stack views in my top-level collection view's cell. Or I'd have a single collection view with a custom layout that laid those groups of cells the way I wanted.

Comment: I can't use stackview because there are other design requirements which collectionview is suitable than a stackview. Could you show me how it's done using layoutAttributesForItem?

Comment: The basic idea is that `layoutAttributesForItem` calculates the `center` and `size` for each cell and that `layoutAttributesForElements` returns the same for all cells that fall within a particular `CGRect`. And `collectionViewContentSize` returns the whole `CGSize` for all of the cells. While it's quite different than what we're talking about here, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41839446/1271826 for an example. To answer it more specifically here, I'd need to know more about how these groups of cells, shown in your picture here are to be laid out with respect to other groups of cells.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. From there you can use `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` to calculate the frame for each cell.

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];

    int half = NUM_ITEMS + 1 / 2;
    int row = indexPath.row % half;
    int col = indexPath.row <= half ? 0 : 1;
    attributes.frame = CGRectMake(CELL_WIDTH * col, CELL_HEIGHT * row, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT);

    return attributes;
}
```

From your example, item at index 3 (**Item4**) would have the frame `0, CELL_HEIGHT * 3, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT` (bottom left), and item at index 4 (**Item5**) would have the frame `CELL_WIDTH, 0, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT` (top right)