# How to create custom circular groupview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I did my first app in swift for ios and now I want to create custom views, the problem I can't find a clear tutor or documention about creating a custom view like android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

I actually trying to create a custom circular viewgroup in iOS, if some can give me an example with commented code how this be done in iOS it'll really help me for all other custom views that I planned to create.

For my circular viewgroup I just want to put each basic view (`UIButton`, `UIImageView`, ...) around center of my circular viewgroup, I read the apple doc about `UIView` and `UICollectionView`, and both can contains zero or more subviews and I don't know what I should use, `UIView` seems less difficult than `UICollectionView`, but `UICollectionView` seems more appropriate for what I want to do (maybe I am wrong) but how implement `CustomCollectionLayout` and how set this layout in `CustomUICollectionView` because I planed to add in future custom drawing and animation.

The most important things that I want to achieve:

1. I want drag my circular groupview from "Object library" (UIview or UICollectionView) and drop onto my view controller scene and set the size (width and height) with "Size Inspector"
2. I want to keep the item size by default, i.e I want drag all item from "Object library" and set the item size from "Size Inspector",
3. place each item center(x, y) point in ViewGroup
4. I want see the preview in InterfaceBuilder

So what class should I implement `UIView` or `UICollectionView`, and what methods should I call, an example with comment it is really helpful

Comment: See the latter half of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41839446/1271826 for example of collection view custom layout to arrange cells in a circle (which is, itself, a permutation of Apple's own demo they showed in WWDC video showing how to do custom layouts). It doesn't check all of the boxes on your check list (notably you won't see the circular arrangement in IB nor will it be in the object library). The other approach, if you want to see it rendered in IB, is to use a `IBDesignable` view, but you may end up writing more code to achieve this. And even that won't show up in the object library.

Comment: If you're looking for off-site demos or tutorials on how to do this, that is unfortunately considered off topic for Stack Overflow.